# Remove numbers at the beginning of a string in txt file

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++

I have a txt file in this format:

```
 1 1970  3878 2 XXXXXXX 10-09-1949 XXXXXXX
 2 1975  4245 2 YYYYYYY 21-11-1955 YYYYYYY
```

I need to remove the numbers at the beginning of the string until the characters begins. So, for example, in the first line I need to remove the "1 1970 3878 2" but not the "10-09-1949" that is after the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:    `^[\d ]+`

Replace by `empty string`.